# How to read the node and its attributes of xml file from Jenkins script file

Tags: jenkins, groovy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<test-run id="2" testcasecount="596" result="Failed" total="596" passed="448" failed="148" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="812" engine-version="3.6.0.0" clr-version="4.0.30319.42000" start-time="2017-01-30 07:19:45Z" end-time="2017-01-30 07:31:25Z" duration="700.676581">
```

I have to read the result attribute from above xml from jenkins file
I could fetch the result from groovy script but unable to fetch from Jenkin script file

How to access xml attributes from JenkinsFile?

i am facing the below issue

**org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new groovy.util.XmlSlurper**

Comment: Could you describe what issues you have when reading the xml from JenkinsFile? Like do you get en error or the attribute is not found?

Comment: find sample in documentation - http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html

Comment: @Rao i couldn't use XmlSlurper in my script

Comment: what do you mean by `JenkinsFile`?

Comment: Jenkin script file

Comment: Are you an administrator of the jenkins you use?

Comment: Above issue cleared by adding script approval in base Jenkins.Now i am facing below issue
**java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c in jenkins**

code:

`def Node = new XmlParser().parse("f${env.WORKSPACE}/TestResult.xml")
   println "Test result: ${Node.@result}"`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming accessing this from groovy is ok, the following works:

```
def str = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<test-run id="2" testcasecount="596" result="Failed" total="596" passed="448" failed="148" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="812" engine-version="3.6.0.0" clr-version="4.0.30319.42000" start-time="2017-01-30 07:19:45Z" end-time="2017-01-30 07:31:25Z" duration="700.676581">
</test-run>    
'''

def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(str)
println "Test result: ${xml.@result}"
```

Note that I added an end tag for the `test-result` element. The at character `@` is used to access attribute values.

The above prints:

```
Test result: Failed
```

Edit: After re-reading I realize you are looking for a non groovy solution. I will leave this here in case a groovy fallback would be useful.